# Spring MVC em páginas HTML sem JSP

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

1 - É possível utilizar dados enviados pelos Controllers do Spring em páginas HTML(usando tags HTML5), para não utilizar JSP?

2 - Se não for possível, como eu posso fazer páginas JSP com Spring MVC com o mínimo de intrusão de código Java nas páginas?

3 - O framework CSS Bootstrap funciona em páginas JSP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1 - É possível utilizar dados enviados pelos Controllers do Spring em páginas HTML(usando tags HTML5), para não utilizar JSP?

Não é possível usar HTML puro, já que a saída gerada com dados de controladores deve ser dinâmica.

> 2 - Se não for possível, como eu posso fazer páginas JSP com Spring MVC com o mínimo de intrusão de código Java nas páginas?

É possível livrar-se dos JSP's com tecnologias de processamento de Templates como [FreeMarker](http://freemarker.org/) ou [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/). A própria [documentação do Spring ensina como fazer a integração](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html) com esses dois frameworks.

Muitos desenvolvedores (como eu) acham que uma linguagem de templates é muito mais adequada para representar a saída HTML do que JPS's. Além disso, JSP's são muito discutíveis do ponto de vista de desempenho e flexibilidade.

Por outro lado, um JSP é mais que suficientes para gerar uma saída em HTML 5 sem intrusão de código Java. Na maioria dos casos, basta usar as *taglibs* adequadas para imprimir valores e fazer laços de repetição sem escrever *scriptlets*.

> 3 - O framework CSS Bootstrap funciona em páginas JSP?

Qualquer tecnologia que gere uma saída HTML válida pode trabalhar com Bootstrap.

É claro que isso pode ser um problema em frameworks *component-based* como Struts ou JSF que geram toda a tela para você, tirando o seu controle sobre a estrutura do código.

Comment: Obrigado por me responder.